# How to retrieve characteristics from an object class?

Tags: java, class, object

I made a class called Harness for a programming assignment. 
It takes in these parameters.

```
public Harness(String make, int modelNo, int numberUsed, String climbingInstructor, boolean loan, String nameOfLoanPerson)
```

I have to make another class now and I need to know the modelNo and the make of certain harnesses to compare it against other make and modelNo's.

How would I retrieve the characteristics from that class and move it to this class?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define all those fields as state of Harness Object and try exposing those fields with getter method and compose Harness in other like:

```
 private String make;
 public Harness(String make,...) {
     this.make = make;
     ..
 }
 public String getMake() {
     return this.make;
 }
```

And access it from another object like:

```
 public class HarnessClient {
     ...
     Harness harness = ...
     String make = harness.getMake();
     ...
 }
```